# Python Tkinter How to get the image of the Canvas?

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

As the title says, I need to get the image of a canvas

To get the image of a Label, I simply type

```
aLable = Label(root,image = AnImage)
aLabel.cget("image")
```

I can check to see if `AmImage` is in `aLabel` using `cget()` so how do I do the same with the `Canvas?` `cget("image")` doesn't seem to work

Comment: Do you want to get back a single image you added to the canvas, or an image of the entire canvas with all objects? For a single image, you should probably keep a reference to the object ID when adding it.

Comment: i need to get a single image from a canvas

Comment: Research the `itemcget` method of the canvas.

Comment: can you give me some links? or explain it to me

Comment: You can refer to the [tk document](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/canvas.htm#M56).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found a way to do it, So I will try to explain it

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk,Image

root = Tk()
An_Image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('flower.jpg'))
Test = Canvas(root, width = 1000, height = 1000)
Test.create_image(25,25, image=An_Image, anchor=CENTER, tag = "abc")
Test.place(x=10,y = 10)
```

A Tag is a name to certain parts of a widget like the Canvas.
`"abc"` is the name of the tag of the image that got created, you can name it however you want, the tag cannot contain spaces and it must be a string `tag = "your_string"`.

[Image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSVKi.png)

The reason we need to add a tag to the item is this

```
Test.itemcget(Tag_id, Item) # Tag_id is the Item tag

#example 
Test.itemcget("abc", "image") # this is how I get the image from the Test Canvas
```